# Debugging with EPIC, Indigo and Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7-x64, eclipse-indigo, activeperl, epic

I'm trying to get the EPIC debugger working with the following setup:

- Eclipse Indigo

  ActivePerl 5.14.2

  EPIC 0.6.44

  Windows 7, 64-bit

When I start the debugger, I get the following message:

```
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine dereference at (null) line 1.
perl5db.pl did not return a true value.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

I've read everything I can find on this **well-known bug (SourceForge ID 2907155)** and tried all of the solutions, to no avail.

- Initially, I was unable to install PadWalker (no version available that is compatible with Windows 7, 64-bit), but then I WAS able to install it by starting the PPM and directly selecting this package from the list of all available packages.
- I also installed PathTools (recommended as a possible fix in the bug report). That caused a rollback of Cwd.pm from 3.6 to 3.3, but that didn't seem critical.
- I then edited Cwd.pm (again, as suggested in the bug report) and removed the `eval` that is considered the root of the problem.
- I closed and re-opened Eclipse. But, I still get the same error.

So, I am out of ideas. Maybe some of the fixes are contra-indicated?

Has anyone got the debugger working for this configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: I have been running for a while now, Eclipse 3.7.1 (I think it's Indigo), EPIC 0.6.44, Strawberry Perl 5.14.2, on Windows 7 64 bit. I have no problems (except a little problem which cropped up recently in one project - trying to set a breakpoint in a different module failed with the message: "Java null pointer exception") - Helen Craigman

Comment: Hi Helen, Thanks for the tip. I'll try using Strawberry Perl.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I solved the problem, and here's how I think I did it (tried a lot of things - including Strawberry, so I'm not sure exactly what worked):

I'm staying with ActivePerl. EPIC tells you to edit the cwd.pm file, which I did, but it didn't help. I later saw that the cwd.pm file was in two places:
- C:\Perl64\lib
- C:\Perl64\site\lib

I had only changed the version in C:\Perl64\lib. When I also changed the version in C:\Perl64\site\lib, everything work.

Gruß, Kim

Answer (score 0):

Add path of the Perl library folder in Eclipse Include Path.

Go to Eclipse : `Eclipse -> Project->Properties->Perl Include Path`

Add Perl lib folder : `Example: D:\Dwimperl\perl\lib`